# AngularJS: How to change the path after refresh the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I want: if the user reloads the page with his redirect to another page.

(Only when updating the page)

Example:
I'm on main/bla and reload the page and I'm redirected to the main/

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
 $state.go('main');
};
```

Does not work for me.

Comment: question was not clear

Comment: Try $location.path('/url');

Comment: What do you mean by *does not work for me*? Is there an error? `onbeforeunload` is not called? `$state.go`does not do the redirect?

Answer (score 0):

Check once if you are using proper injector in js controller or is there any other error on console.
Check for:

1. you have given proper state name $state.go('main'),it should defined in routing.
2. Should use injector $state in controller.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot happening when you want to change states.

For one, it could trigger extra network activities such as resource download. There isn't enough time for angular to change states, change URL and go through the lifecycle of navigating routes.

some options:

- Do the redirect after the refresh happens (save something in localstorage, cookies, ..)
- Redirect manually, update `document.location` or similar